# XAML - DataTemplate : unexplainable exception thrown (Unhandled exception)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datatemplate

Image following 2 datatemplates:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateGridDeleteBtn">
        <Button   Tag="{Binding stamnr}" Click="ButtonGridDelete_Click"   ToolTipService.ToolTip="Verwijderen aanvraag mutatie">
            <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="../Images/DeleteRed.png" Width="20" Height="20" />

            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateProcessRequest">
        <Button Tag="{Binding stamnr}" Click="ButtonProcess_Click" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Verwerken zonder de Wasserij te contacteren">
            <StackPanel  VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="../Images/Process.png" Width="20" Height="20" />

            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I'm having an `Unhandled exception` when adding the `Click-event` to my `templateProcessRequest`. Yet the code behind them is exactly the same (see below)

```
Private Sub ButtonGridDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonProcess_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
End Sub
```

If i remove the `Click-Event` from my second template then the exception isn't thrown. What is the reason of this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It had nothing to do with the XAML itself. The exception was thrown due to `inheritance`. 
This control acts as parent for multiple other documents. And if the method shown in the Click event of the parameter isn't present in the 'sub'-controls then an unhandled exception is thrown.

Example:

```
MainControl A
      => Has method ButtonProcess_Click

                   SubControl B inherits MainControl A
                   => Has method ButtonProcess_Click


                   SubControl C inherits MainControl A
                   => Doesn't Have method ButtonProcess_Click
```

An exception will be thrown in SubControl C but not in A or B.